# How can I do this kind of routing in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a link like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/users/view/1
```

But I want the users to go to:

```
www.mydomain.com/profile/1
```

When they type/click the first link. I have already read this page and I can do some basic stuff with this, but still I couldn't figure out this one:

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html

I appreciate any help and explanation(I'm on version 2.x). Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Someone told me to use this and it worked:

```
Router::connect(
    '/profile/:id', 
    array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'view'), 
    array('id' => '[0-9]+', 'pass' => array('id'))
);
```

Now `/profile/1` does the work of `/users/view/1`.